# How do I remove layers of a SpatRaster using terra?

Tags: r, raster, terra

I am running a loop of multiple datasets with data from 1950-2014. My SpatRaster also spans this time period with 65 layers. I realized that some of my datasets are missing data from a number of years (e.g. only have data from 63 years), causing an error in my loop. I have now set it up so that the missing years and corresponding layers are identified within the loop, as such:

```
# Identify any years with missing data and skip these layers of "temperature_raster" in the loop
  missing_years <- setdiff(seq(1950, 2014), unique(df$year))
  # Determine the layers corresponding to the missing years
  missing_layers <- which(seq(1950, 2014) %in% missing_years)
```

I would now like to modify my "temperature_rasters" to delete the layers that correspond to those stored in the vector object "missing_layers". I'd like to do this with the terra package, if possible.

Initially I tried to integrate this into the loop, like this:

```
for (l in setdiff(1:nlyr(temperature_rasters), missing_layers)) {
  # rest of loop
}
```

When this didn't work, I wanted to modify the raster directly before using it in the loop, like this:

```
temperature_rasters <- temperature_rasters[-c(missing_layers)]
```

But that also didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking a question, always include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example* using data created with code, or with files that ship with R. See the examples in the R help files and the Q and A on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really used to `terra`, but I think that an SpatRaster object may have multiple layers that we can call with a name (string).

It is hard to understand if the layer names are a string representing a year (ex. `"1950"`), but I will assume. My suggestion would be to use a logicial vector to verify if the missing years are **not** in the years string vector.

```
all_years = seq(1950, 1958)
all_years_char = as.character(all_years)
missing_years <- c( 1953, 1954)
missing_layers <- as.character(missing_years)

year_to_read <- all_years_char[!all_years_char %in% missing_layers]
```

So you could use

```
for (l in year_to_read) {
  # rest of loop
}
```

Additionnal information should be provided.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, the years are layer names (not the time attribute).

Example data

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(nrow=2, ncol=2, nlyr=10, names=2000:2009)
```

If you wanted to remove 2006, 2007 and 2008 you could do

```
missing_years <- c("2006", "2007", "2008")
y <- subset(x, missing_years, negate=TRUE)

names(y)
#[1] "2000" "2001" "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" "2009"
```

Or

```
i <- match(missing_years, names(x))
y <- x[[-i]]
```